# Embed website in my website using backend

Tags: python, html, web

I want to embed a website on my web gui (in python) for my personal application but the site doesnt allow iframe.

So i want to use my remote server as a middleman to download the pages and embed them into what it serves my client.

But I need to download all the files, js, css, with the pages and load them like an iframe in the page.

So if I can make this work, what do i need to do on the client and server side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could probably use [pywebview](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview) on the client. No middleman required.

Edit: Since OP stated it's not a python client application, a [proxy](https://github.com/luugiathuy/WebProxyPython) acting as a middle man could be used to make it work in the browser.

Please note that if you do this for anything other than personal use, you might run into legal problems.

Comment: the server is remote. its a web application

Comment: You wanted to use an iframe. iframes are client-side.

Comment: everything has to be in the web app. i cant have any software on the client machine

Comment: I see. The python tag and your use of "my client" threw me off. So it's a personal application for your own use, running in a browser? A [proxy script](https://github.com/luugiathuy/WebProxyPython) might be the solution then.